# Show that $W$ is a subspace of $P_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W = \{ p(x) \in P_5 \mid p(0) = p(1) = 0 \}$.

a) Show that $W$ is a subspace of $P_5$.

b) Find a basis for $W$.

c) What is $\dim(W)$?

For part a), I need to show three things (I believe):

1) Closure under addition

2) Closure under multiplication

3) Show the vector zero is in the subset

I'm just unsure of how to show this closure with this example, I've done closure with other examples. I just don't know what $W$ really is, and what to do with it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your doubt about W?

Comment: For a basis: not that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $5$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then $f$ is of the form  $x(x-1)g(x)$ with $g$ a polynomial of degree at most $3$ **(why?)**. A basis of $P_5$ is given by $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5\}$, does this give you an idea how to find a basis of $W$?

Comment: @gimusi I'm a bit slow with this so my apologies, I'm just unsure of what $p(0) = p(1) = 0$ Is telling us. Why is this important to know? And what about like $p(2)$ Thanks for the help

Comment: @LocoSap I was indeed awaiting for yuor reply in order to understand what your doubts was. I've added a full solution now. Note that for the closure we need also to check that $p(1)$ satisfy the definition and not only p(0). Moreover I present a way to find explicitely a basis by definition and not guessing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure note that   $$ (P+Q)(0)=P(0)+Q(0) = 0+0 =0$$

$$ (\lambda P)(0)= \lambda (P(0))= \lambda 0 =0 $$

For basis consider $$\{ x(x-1), x^2(x-1), x^3(x-1) , x^4(x-1)\}$$

Thus the dimension of $W$   is four.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, I wasn't registering that p(x) was what we were looking at, completely over my head, thanks for helping it click.

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with polynomials of degree 5 that is

$$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$$

with the following properties

- $p(0)=0 $
- $p(1)=0 $

Firstly let check that **W is a subspace** indeed

1. $p,q\in W\quad r=p+q\implies r(0)=p(0)+q(0)=0 \land r(1)=p(1)+q(1)=0\\\implies r\in W$
2. $p\in W\quad c\in\mathbb{R} \quad r(x)=cp(x) \implies r(0)=cp(0)=0 \land
       r(1)=cp(1)=0\implies r(x)\in W$
3. $r(x)=0 \implies r(0)=0 \land r(1)=0 \implies r(x)\in W$

To **find a basis** let find the explicit expression for $p(x)$ by the given properties

- $p(0)=0 \implies f=0$
- $p(1)=0 \implies a+b+c+d+e=0\implies e=-a-b-c-d$

that is

$$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2-(a+b+c+d)x=\\=a(x^5-x)+b(x^4-x)+c(x^3-x)+d(x^2-x)$$

thus a basis is

$$\{ (x^2-x), (x^3-x), (x^4-x) , (x^5-x)\}$$

from which we also deduce that the **dimension** of $W$ is $4$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function T: $P_5$ -> **R**$^2$ where T(p) = [p(0) , p(1)], then W = {p:T(p)=0}. Given a vector space V, sets of the form {v:T(v)=0} are subspaces of V iff T is linear. So showing that W is subspace is equivalent to showing that T(ap+bq) = aT(p)+bT(q).

In other words, W is a subspace of V iff it there exists some linear operator for which W is the null space. So part (b) comes down to finding a basis of the null space of T, and (c) follows simply by counting the number of vectors in (b). It can also be found by finding the rank of T and subtracting it from the dimension of P$_5$.